# The name of the file resulted from a Mobile Push Data Extract to use in SQL for file transfer

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-extract, tracking-extract

I need some help with understanding how to build an SQL from Mobile Push Extract that needs some transformation to the data like time zone, before being transferred to a AWS bucket.

I have an automation that starts with a Mobile Push Detail Extract Report and I need to use SQL to pull all of the fields in the report to a Data extension and then transfer the file to further.

I need to import the extract results to a data extension prior to doing an SQL or can I pull directly from the Mobile push extract report activity, isn't it?

I appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a report in SQL. You need to create the report first and import it into a Data Extension. Then run the SQL to pull and transform data from that DE and save it in another DE. Then, run a data extension extract and transfer to AWS.